# Encode URL while send ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I use cakePHP and it generate ajax

```
/animemanga/animes/search/page:1?type%5B0%5D=3&amp;genre%5B0%5D=20&amp;genre%5B1%5D=4&amp;info%5B0%5D=episodes&amp;info%5B1%5D=released&amp;info%5B2%5D=rating&amp;info%5B3%5D=synopsis&amp;info%5B4%5D=completed&amp;info%5B5%5D=rating_count&amp;info%5B6%5D=name&amp;info%5B7%5D=id&amp;info%5B8%5D=name&amp;info%5B9%5D=id
```

cakePHP encoded: & => &apm;
will create error while use with Ajax. I use Jquery, browser Opera. how can this solve ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)